# Php script url with special characters

Tags: php, url, character, inline

I have this php code in a Wordpress page

```
$str = 's.aspx?sm=Q830I7SJZvuSP3HzDfFlVA%3d%3d';

printf('<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/.urlencode($str)." target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.anyfood.gr/net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/evaluation2.jpg" style="padding:20px;">
       </a>'
);
```

but the link doesn't work, I've tried several possible tricks using single quotes, etc.
but I can't figure it out...Any ideas?

Comment: or try this `htmlspecialchars($str);`

Comment: @marilena6 I think you forgot mark one answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you won't have to use `urldecode()` when accessing `GET` parameters. Use it as follow:

```
$str = 's.aspx?sm=' . urlencode ('Q830I7SJZvuSP3HzDfFlVA%3d%3d');

echo '<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/'.$str.'" target="_blank">
         <img src="http://www.anyfood.gr/net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/evaluation2.jpg" style="padding:20px;">
     </a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 's.aspx?sm=Q830I7SJZvuSP3HzDfFlVA%3d%3d';

printf('
 *<*a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/".urlencode($str) target="_blank">
    *<*img src="http://www.anyfood.gr/net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/evaluation2.jpg" style="padding:20px;">
  </a>
');
```

**remove the * at the starting of Anchor tag and image tag **

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
<?php
$str = 's.aspx?sm=Q830I7SJZvuSP3HzDfFlVA%3d%3d';

printf('<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/%1$s " target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.anyfood.gr/net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/evaluation2.jpg" style="padding:20px;"> </a>', urlencode($str));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 's.aspx?sm=Q830I7SJZvuSP3HzDfFlVA%3d%3d';

printf('< a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/%s" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.anyfood.gr/net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/evaluation2.jpg" style="padding:20px;">
       </ a>', urlencode($str));
```

check this.